# Remove value with decimals from a vector

Tags: r

I have a vector, for example

```
value <- rnorm(10)
> value
 [1] -0.88227008 -0.02128920 -0.25586231  0.44447101  2.97644568 -1.52610211 -0.52591668 -1.01474716  0.08093004  0.22535990
```

I want to remove one particular value. Let's assume that I can't remove using the position of the value in the vector because the position changes when I update the dataset with new values. If for example I want to remove the value `0.44447101` I would do the following:

```
value[value==0.44447101] <- NA
```

However, when I print the vector, the value is still there:

```
> value
 [1] -0.88227008 -0.02128920 -0.25586231  0.44447101  2.97644568 -1.52610211 -0.52591668 -1.01474716  0.08093004  0.22535990
```

How can I do this simple task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
value[round(value,8)==0.44447101] <- NA
```